Differences between ballistic models on Drama/MIDAS
I am a student who is evaluating the impact of micro meteoroids on satellite external tubes using MIDAS tool on DRAMA by ESA. I want to verify how the probability of no penetration changes by adding an MLI.
However, up to this point I have used a simplified single-wall model by entering the thickness and density of the tubes as input to the model. I would like to check how much the probability of no penetration increases by adding a MLI, but I only know the thickness.
In the more advanced models of MIDAS (e.g. SRL Original) there is a parameter that could be my case: "equivalent MLI thickness". I tried to simulate with SRL Original the same set up (without MLI) of the single wall model, only entering thickness and density of the tubes in the editable parameters. The other parameters (inner and outer boumper thickness, spacing, etc.) are set to 0.
Obviously the single wall model is more conservative than the triple wall model of the SRL, therefore I expected differences but not so high: from 95% probability of no penetration I went to 99.6%.
Does it make sense what I did? Is it a reliable result? If not, what do you recommend?
Tanks in advance!

I have picked up somewhere that the first layer (the MLI) might have a different effect depending on how far it is from the victim. I can't remember much, at a guess perhaps this only relates to whether the first layer is resting against the victim vs. just far enough away for the initial collision products to have dispersed. I'm not familiar with MIDAS or "SRL original", these memories come from a NASA document about applying ballistic limit equations. If I find it I will post a link.

... down in the detail though, it sounds like you want someone else's worked example, any material, just so you can run it to sanity check your results. There is lots of NASA sponsored work out on the internet so that is one option. Is there a forum associated with DRAMA/MIDAS where you can ask about setting up the model?  Good luck with this.

If you are an ESA Member State national, you can register and maybe get support on space-codev? My experience with DRAMA and MIDAS is limited to running some examples...

I'd forgotten I posted an answer to another question here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45271/10791 which might be helpful - it also links on to https://web.archive.org/web/20130225001045/http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/TP-2003-210788.pdf. Also perhaps here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6416/10791
